# How to measure frequency with external timer counter on BeagleBone Black?

Tags: assembly, timer, arm, beagleboneblack

I need to measure the frequency with a BeagleBone (400 kHz) and for this I would like to use the BeagleBone timers (F = 1/((timer1+timer2)/2)). How to read the external timer counter?
I tried using PRU but didn't get the accuracy (https://github.com/SuperEjik/frequency-measurement-with-PRU-BeagleBone-CYCLE-register-/blob/main/cycle.pru0.c).

Also in the datasheet I found a description of timers and registers, but unfortunately there are no examples with code.Is there an example with code how to read the counter of an external timer using arm assembler for am335x ?

Comment: so you are trying to do some form of measurement...from an application...running on linux...and want to access the hardware directly?

Comment: Yes that's right. A similar question has already been asked on this forum (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572540/how-to-read-the-external-timer-counter-on-the-beaglebone-black). 
Therefore I would like to know how this can be implemented using code (arm assembler or c)?